React Native Expo APK not sendung request to locally hosted Python flask server endpoint
i have an app build through expo. I have succcessfully build the apk. I have local server hosted through python flask in my laptop. My app needs to send data to that server api endpoint. How to do that since my server is locally hosted in my computer.What necessary permissions and things i need to do after connecting my mobile to my laptop wifi?
Tried Everything got nothing

"Tried everything" such as? Did you try using the LAN IP for the server endpoint?

I mean I tried giving required permissions to my apk but still the apk is not able to send request to my locally hosted python flask server. My mobile Chrome browser is able to access that endpoint but why my react native expo is not able to send request to that endpoint? The endpoint is the IPv4 address that I got through ipconfig

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

My App that is built using React Expo is not able to send data to my local server which is a python flask local server currently running on my laptop.
